# Compare months (string) in two workbooks and loop

Tags: string, vba, loops, copy

I've created a macro that compares a cell in a master/main workbook (sheet "Basis") with approx 20 workbooks in a fixed folder. If there is a match, a cell value is copied to the master workbook. This process continues for each workbook in the folder. The macro works fine. Now, I would like to expand the macro also to recognize for which month data has to be copied in the main workbook. Every workbook from the fixed folder has the month in cell `B9`, fx "February - 2016". The `B9`cells have to be compared to the first row of the Basis sheet in the main workbook. When there is a match between the dates, then the macro that I've created so far is initiated.

Currently the code is fixed to loop through cells in column `I` of the main workbook, but should recognize whether the workbooks are in February, March, April and so on. I imagine I need to use `InStr()` and `Offset()`, but I'm not sure how especially because the months in the main workbook are inside merged cells.

This is the "Basis" sheet of the main/master workbook:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
Sub combineall()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Call lista
    Call CopyLookup

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Basis").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Visible = False

End Sub

Sub CopyLookup()

    Dim Path As String
    Dim Fil As String
    Dim strName As String
    Dim wbk_main As Workbook, wbk1 As Workbook
    Dim ws_main As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim rng_main As Range, rng1 As Range
    Dim c_main As Range, c1 As Range
    i = 2

    While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    t = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Cells(i, 1)

     'Define fixed path
    Set wbk_main = ActiveWorkbook
    Path = "I:\BS\PLAN\HQ\Saud\Opgaver\Opgaver Kompensation Fakturering\Test VBA\Test Månedsbilag\" & t

    q = 1
     'Start outer loop
    Do While q <> ""

        Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open(Path)
        Set ws1 = wbk1.Sheets(1)

         'Split cell if containing many values
        ws1.Range("B10").Select
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("R10"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        'Create range objects for the two columns to be compared:
        Set rng1 = ws1.Range("R10:AL10")

        Set rng_main = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Basis").Range("I4:I19")

         'Loop through each cell in col I:
        For Each c_main In rng_main
            If c_main.Value <> "" Then
                For Each c1 In rng1
                    If c1.Value = c_main.Value Then
                         'Copy value to main workbook:
                        c_main.Offset(0, 3).Value = wbk1.Sheets(1).Range("F13").Value
                        q = ""
                         'Move on to next cell in sheet 2:
                        Exit For '(exits the "For Each c1 In rng1" loop)

                    End If
                Next c1
            End If
        Next c_main

        rng1.Delete
        wbk1.Close False

    Loop

    i = i + 1
    Wend

End Sub


Sub lista()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet
    .Name = "List"
    End With

    fldrpath = "I:\Fixed folder"
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(fldrpath)
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "The files found in " & objFolder.Name & "are:"

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = objFile.Name
    Next

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You would need to use offset, with a Match function in also, so something like OFFSET(A1,0,MATCH("mar",$A$1:$C$1,0)) or something like OFFSET(A1,0,MATCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"mmm"),$A$1:$C$1,0))

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, why are you using "TODAY()"? I would like the macro to recognize which months are stated in the B9 cells (which are fixed for every workbook in the fixed folder) and then compare them to the months . It can be any month. The folder is updated with workbooks containing the next month and the data associated with that month.

Comment: Today was to show how to search for current date.

Comment: Hmm, but I want the macro to be more dynamic and recognize which month is stated in the workbooks and then copy data over for the relevant cells for the relevant month in the main workbook.

Comment: well then you'd modify the one where I've used "mar" as March and the value being the cell contents.

Comment: I know :) But I will have to do this 12 times (one time for every month) to check which month is stated in the workbooks. This is in a waw resembles what I've done so far. I can just replace the I column manually in the main workbook to whichever month is stated in the workbooks in the fixed folder. Would like to automatize this process.

Comment: you would use the value from the sheet in match, so something like offset("A:A"),0,match(text(inputworksheet.range("a1").value,"mmm-yy"), etc...

Comment: Not sure how to do this :/